# How to use WordPress get recent posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how to use Wordpress get recents posts inside the post area?

I have this code from the WordPress website for getting the recent posts:

```
 wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output);
```

If i echo this function inside the post page body (place where i write my post) i get only the exact php code showing as a text?

```
    <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

The other code for showing the recent 5 posts also render to the post page as text and i don't know why?

How to use it correctly?

Comment: What do you mean only text string output?

Comment: How are you looking to format the posts ie.. title, excerpt, readmore etc...

Comment: Hi, I edited my question, when you write <?php echo "Hello"; ?> you get Hello, put when i write this code inside the post are (where to write your post content and html from dashboard) i get the exact <?php echo "Hello"; ?> on the page when i view the post page on the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain about what you mean with "post area". With "string text output" I presume you mean unformatted text links in a list.

If you need to have more control over how to format the output (to make it more like a regular post listing for example), use a regular WP Query for this. You can get the 5 latest blog entries with these arguments:

```
$recent_args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => 5,
    "orderby"        => "date",
    "order"          => "DESC"
);      

$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $recent_args );
```

And to loop through them just use the regular WordPress main loop structure:

```
if ( $recent_posts -> have_posts() ) :
    while ( $recent_posts -> have_posts() ) :

    $recent_posts -> the_post();

    // ... Use regular 'the_title()', 'the_permalink()', etc. loop functions here.

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I'm not looking for format, In WP dashboard, you create a new post, you paste the php code for that function, i get the exact code showing on the blog post page? this is my question, where should i copy the function code to get it the recent posts?

Comment: So you're trying to get recent posts showing within a single blog post (inside the post itself)? A shortcode would be probably a correct route to achieve this.

Comment: I want to make a shortcode, this is my main goal, but i need to know how to use the wp functions to get results?  i know the wp function for getting recent post, but how to use it (try it or test it) to get results? how to echo the results returned by the function? after i understand this and see it, then i can try the shortcode by using the add_shortcode() function. thank you.